# Counting iterations

Tags: vb.net, for-loop, nested-loops

I am working on a homework problem and it is asking how many times this code displays the word "Message" in the console.
I don't understand how to solve this.

```
For i As Integer = 1 To 10 Step 1
  For j As Integer = i To 10 Step 1
    Console.WriteLine("Message")
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Sorry for the poor format, I think the message still comes across.

Comment: Please it a go on your own first and then ask if your reasoning is correct.  You'll learn more that way.

Comment: This is not the original question. Please don't change the question once it's been answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outer loop executes 34 times, because it starts at 1 and increments by 1 each time stopping at 34, because the 35th iteration will exceed the upper limit on the loop of 34.

The inner loop executes 39 times, because it starts at 1 and increments by 2 each time (`1`, `3`, `5`, `7`, etc.), stopping when the value is greater than 78, but since 40th iteration will equal a value of 79, which is greater than 78 it will not execute the 40th iteration.

34 times 39 = 1,326, so you will see the message `Message` written 1,326 times in the console.

In general terms, you can break it down to this:

> i * (j / 2)

where `i` equals outer loop iterations (34) and `j` equals inner loop iterations (78 / 2 = 39).

Comment: Fantastic! That makes much more sense! Got the flu and couldn't attend this lecture.

Comment: But what if I reworded the problem to look like this. For i as integer = 1 to 10 step 1... for j as integer = i to 10 step 1....

Comment: I can put it into Visual Studio but I want to understand the logic behind it. Not trying to be lazy.

Comment: @user2860326 - for the reworded problem, just plug the values into the generalized equation. Note though that since you changed the step, the equation is now simply `i * j`, so `10 * 10` equals `100`.

Comment: @user2860326 Your revised problem has less than 100 iterations. Work it out by hand so that you understand what it does.

Comment: @user2860326 - oh that is `j = i to 10` and not `1 to 10`?

Comment: yes i, i know it has 31 iterations because i plugged it into VS. I just want to know why.

Comment: @user2860326 31 iterations is easily within the human scale. Pretend that you're the computer and step through each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

As has been shown by other answers, the number of iterations is 34 * (78/2) = 1326. To gain more understanding of what is going on, I suggest you write your code as below and watch how the values if i, j, k change - Here K is showing the current iteration number - Pay special attention to the last line:

```
Dim k As Integer = 1
For i As Integer = 1 To 34
    For j As Integer = 1 To 78 Step 2
        Console.WriteLine("Message" & " i:" & i.ToString() & " j:" & j.ToString() & " k:" & k.ToString())
        k += 1
    Next
Next
```

You will see output like:

```
Message i:1 j:1 k:1

Message i:1 j:3 k:2

Message i:1 j:5 k:3

Message i:1 j:7 k:4

Message i:1 j:9 k:5

...

Message i:34 j:75 k:1325

Message i:34 j:77 k:1326
```

Answer (score 0):

**1326 times**

The inner loop iterates 39 times (78 numbers / 2 step), and the outer loop iterates 34 times (34 numbers / 1 step). The outer loop will iterate 34 times, and each time, the inner loop will also iterate. So:

34 outer loop iterations * 39 inner loop iterations (each time) = 1326.